# Change query from cat id to slug or name?

Tags: wp-query, loop

I'm using the following query to fetch posts in a category (10). I would like to change this code to use the category slug or name instead of the id number as this often changes when I move sites about.??

```
<?php $custom_query = new WP_Query(array ('cat' => 10, 'showposts' => 1));
query_posts($custom_query);
while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();?>
```

I've tried changing ('cat' => 'books'...   ('cat_name => 'books'...  & also ('cat_slug => "books"...   but nothing seems to work.

Many thanks

Following the first suggestion I've now got this working:

```
<?php 
$query = new WP_Query('category_name=books');
while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>
```

But now need help combining the "posts_per_page" bit of the query??

Answer (score 3):

Lets start by removing the `query_posts()` from your code since you already have it's better brother `new WP_Query`.

Then what you will need is to use the `category_name` param on your `WP_Query`.

You should always search on the [WP_Query page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) before you ask here, you can find more referencers there.

---

Here is how @speedypancake resolved the issue:

```
<?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query(
    array( 
        'posts_per_page' => '10', 
        'category_name' => 'books'
    )
);
while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();
    // Do what you want
endwhile;
```

Comment: You mean like this??
<?php $custom_query = new WP_Query(array ('cat_name' => 'books', 'showposts' => 15));
    while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();?>

Answer (score 0):

Following Bordoni's lead, and with a bit of trial and error, finally got it working

```
<?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 
'posts_per_page' => '10', 
'category_name' => 'books'
 ) );
while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
?>
```

@Bordoni - Thanks for the hint!

Comment: don't forget to flag the answer as the correct one ;)